# edittext.getdrawing cache not working.Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-edittext, drawingcache

I need to convert string in the edittext to bitmap, but i am not getting the string but instead i am getting this (see the image)[image]

my code is as follows

```
 Canvas c=new Canvas();

     MainActivity.editText.setCursorVisible(false);
     MainActivity.editText.buildDrawingCache();
     Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(MainActivity.editText.getDrawingCache());

     System.out.println("string is "+MainActivity.editText.getText().toString());


File f =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Photo Text");
     if(!f.exists())
     {
         f.mkdirs();
     }
     f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(),
             String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +"phototext.jpg");
     if(!f.exists())
     {
         try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }


     try {
         bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     c.drawBitmap(bmp,0,0, mPaint);
```

Please suggest me. I need the string from the edittext as a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the text of the `ExitText` and then draw it on `Canvas` with `drawText()`?

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
```

and set the canvas height and width depending of text height and length.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but I think creating a bitmap from the string is better because I need to move the text ontouch to position it on another bitmap. can you suggest some more possibilities as per my requirements.